# AsyncAwait a WCF Call

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have a MVC4 Application which waits for a third party subsystem. Each request takes 2 to 5 Seconds. The communication is done via WCF and i use NET 4.5.

Currently i wait synchronous to the answer and show then results. All sql queries after the result is received cannot be moved in between the async and await, as they are depended on the result.

Does it make sense anyway to apply the AsyncAwait pattern?

Does it reduce the amount of threads inside the IIS?

Sample:

```
client2 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
string res = await client2.GetHello2Async();
```

Comment: Yes, it does make sense.

Comment: Example of proxy can be viewed in http://www.guruumeditation.net/async-await-with-wcf

Comment: thx. i know. my question was less how, more if it makes sense if i do nothing between the request is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, switching to `async`-`await` is going to decrease the number of `ThreadPool` threads used by your code. That's the primary reason for using `async`-`await` in server-side applications.

Comment: @PauloMorgado [Your suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2288660) is wrong. There is no special “request handling thread pool”, in ASP.NET, there is just the single `ThreadPool`.